# Magento 2 Component Manager Won't Load componentGrid/components Times Out

Tags: magento2, component-manager

Magento is version 2.1.2 the issue is on the system > web setup wizard > component manager the page loads forever (ajax loading icon spins). My server is:

Litespeed 5.0.9

PHP version 7.0.12 (all magento 2 requirements met)

Using suPHP in Litespeed

The error is:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in <b>/home/rentinst/public_html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php</b> on line <b>539</b><br />
```

on the ajax call: 
http://testinst.rent-manager.com/setup/index.php/componentGrid/components

The code that the error refers to is:

```
$includedData = json_decode($this->cache->read($cacheKey), true);
```

I have already tried the things listed on these 2 pages: 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4756
https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Magento-2-Component-manager-won-t-sync-Continuos-quot-please/td-p/37204

actually maybe others have the same issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4546

but any ideas?

I have:

1) Checked and reset all folder permissions, they are all ok. I use:
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
and made sure that my public_html is also 755

2) Cleared out var/di, var/cache, var/generation

3) Made sure and re-verified that the Magento public and private access keys are ok they are in system > web setup wizard > system config (they are also stored in var/composer_home/auth.json)

Just a guess but perhaps it is timing out with one of the "providers"? Any debugging or guesses on how to fix this?

Ok so I did a fresh Magento 2 install and the component manager is working, so it is for sure one of the packages/modules I have installed, does anyone know how to correct the package so the component manager doesn't timeout?

Comment: you helped me with similar issue, turned out when using static data in the ConfigProvider (as opposed to API call) the JS component loads as expected, timeout was my trigger, I think I'm moving my API call somewhere else for now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need configure your php and increases `max_execution_time` to 600 (10min) for example.